Other Methods for encrypting Login credential - Fernet Not Working
I've been creating a website for my rhythm gaming community this last months, I tried implementing a login page so that users can easily fill out tournament forms if they want to join a specific contest.
So for extra security, I tried using cryptography. Fernet as my encryption method. But for some reason, When I try logging in after registration, my encrypted username changes to something different even though I'm using a single key.
Here's my current script:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,redirect
import tweepy
import sqlite3
import discord
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

app = Flask(__name__)

main_key = open('key.key', 'rb')
encryptor = Fernet(main_key.read())

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usernameInput = request.form['username']
        userpassInput = request.form['password']

        userInput = str(encryptor.encrypt(usernameInput.encode('utf-8'))) #Encrypts the form from the html 
        userpass = str(encryptor.encrypt(userpassInput.encode('utf-8')))

        db_connect = sqlite3.connect("accounts.db")
        cur = db_connect.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM accountsDB WHERE userName=? or accessCode=?""", (userInput, userInput))
        userAccountName = cur.fetchone()
        print(userInput)
        print(userAccountName)
        
        if userAccountName:
            if userAccountName[0] == userInput and userAccountName[4] == userpass:
                return redirect('/userAccountPage', code=302)
            elif userAccountName[0] == userInput and userAccountName[4] != userpass:
                return 'Wrong Password'
        else:
            return 'No user Found'
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/registration", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registrationPage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username_reg = request.form['username']
        userCode_reg = request.form['aime-access-code']
        userMaiName_reg = request.form['maimaiIGN']
        userpassword_reg = request.form['initialPassword']
        

        enc_username = str(encryptor.encrypt(username_reg.encode('utf-8')))
        print(enc_username)
        enc_code = str(encryptor.encrypt(userCode_reg.encode('utf-8')))
        enc_IGN = str(encryptor.encrypt(userMaiName_reg.encode('utf-8')))
        enc_pass = str(encryptor.encrypt(userpassword_reg.encode('utf-8')))

        db_connect = sqlite3.connect("accounts.db")
        cur = db_connect.cursor()   
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO accountsDB(userName, accessCode, maimaiIGN, userPassword) VALUES (?,?,?,?)""",
                    (enc_username,enc_code,enc_IGN,enc_pass))
        
        db_connect.commit()
        return redirect('/', code=302)
    
    return render_template('registration.html')

I can't find any errors whatsoever. So I concluded it to be something between Fernet's encryption method. So, Is there any better encryption method for a website that I can use?

A symmetric encryption is not suitable for encrypting password for login, use at least a cryptographic hash or better a key derivation function to store and verify the password.

If you want to compare encrypted data, you need to decrypt the data first and compare plaintext. Proper encryption is designed to produce different output even when the same input is used. However, as mentioned in the previous comment, in this case you should be using a password-based key derivation function like argon2 or bcrypt, or even pbkdf2.

Firstly, is it really necessary to encrypt the username? In my opinion, the username is going to be seen by all other users so there is no point. Secondly, I think it would be more practical to hash the password (and username, if you really want to) than to encrypt it. Check out this article about the difference between hashing and encryption.

Werkzeug provides a good hashing algorithm and is very simple to use. Here is a very small example that might help you. 
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

# Btw, never use this password, as person who does tryhackme and hackthebox
# challenges, I can assure it will be cracked in a couple of milleseconds
secret = generate_password_hash('password1234') # generate hash

user_input = input('Password: ') # Get user input

# Is it the correct password?
if check_password_hash(secret, user_input):
    print("Authenticated")
else:
    print("Wrong Password")

Note: If you have installed flask, werkzeug is already installed, you do not need to do a pip install.
